# Why is :$\displaystyle {e}^\sqrt{2}$ is known to be transcedental number but ${\sqrt{2}}^ {e}$ is not known?

Tags: irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

I'm confused why $\displaystyle {e}^\sqrt{2}$ is known to be transcendental number but in the same time ${\sqrt{2}}^ {e}$ is not even known , why we can't deduce any thing from  $\displaystyle {e}^\sqrt{2}$ to know more about irrationality of ${\sqrt{2}}^ {e}$ ?

Comment: Why do you think that one number should have any sort of relationship with the other number?

Comment: look for example  both of sqrt(3)^2 and 2^(sqrt(3)) also transdental

Comment: @zeraouliarafik So? A specific example doesn't suggest a general pattern.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to expect $a^b$ to share properties with $b^a$, in general. For example, consider $({1\over 2})^{-1}$ versus $(-1)^{1\over 2}$.

(In fact, "swapping the exponent" isn't even well defined! E.g. $1^2=1^3$ but $2^1\not=3^1$.)